# How can I delete a (null) app in usage?

Tags: applications, iphone, storage, bug, ios

In my usage list(settings>general>storage & iCloud usage>manage storage), there is an app that registers as (null) with no icon, a version number that doesn't match anything I've previously downloaded, and it's taking up storage space. I first noticed it about a week or two ago. And no, I can't download recent apps to find the one that it is, because I downloaded multiple apps recently, and didn't notice the (null) app until my storage was critically low and I was looking to delete something. I am running iOS 9.2.1 on an iPhone 5C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

App Store>Updates>Purchased

1. View the apps you deleted
2. Find the app which about the same size with NULL app or version that match to the "Null" version
3. Download the app again
4. Remove it again and delete the cache

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks! The other one randomly went away eventually, but another one popped up, and this helped